# JLabel - Change position of Title

Tags: java, swing, layout, alignment, jlabel

In a (Java Swing) JLabel the title is usually placed behind the JLabel's icon. Is it possible to move the text (e.g. before or under the icon image)?

I hope my question makes sense to you, thanks in advance!

Comment: You can set the position of the text relative to the icon. See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html

Answer (score 2):

Note that labels are not opaque by default. If you need to paint the label's background, it is recommended that you turn its opacity property to "true". The following code snippet shows how to do this.

```
label.setOpaque(true);
```

sample code to set the position of the text, relative to the icon:

```
ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("images/middle.gif");
. . .
label1 = new JLabel("Image and Text",
                    icon,
                    JLabel.CENTER);
//Set the position of the text, relative to the icon:
label1.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
label1.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
```

See *Swing Tutorial* on [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) for detail description.